# Update ComboBox Dropdown After BindingSource is Changed

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I've looked through a bunch of examples online but I can't find anything that works (or I'm doing it wrong).

The ComboBox is bound like this to a Dictionary of (String, String) and Nothing:

```
cbBox.DataSource = New BindingSource(dictStrings.Keys, Nothing)
```

However, after `dictStrings.Add(s1, s2)` is called, the Dropdown menu for the ComboBox does not list the newly added value to `dictStrings`. How can I fix this? I've tried rebinding the `datasource` but it just leaves the dropdown menu blank. I tried to use the `ResetBindings()` function but that wouldn't work as well. Thank you.

Comment: The same problem exists using a `List<T>` as a datasource - they dont watch for changes to the contents or provide notifications.  In place of a List you can use a `BindingList<T>` but for a dictionary you need to write a custom collection class perhaps implementing IDictionary and providing notices. An `ObservableCollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))` might work (havent tried)

Comment: I checked and an ObservableDictionary built from IDictionary and INotifyCollectionChanged is cool but it wont help this problem - it needs IBindingList which is not easy to implement with a Dictionary as a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new binding, but you would lose your current index position, and if you have the SelectedIndexChanged event wired up, that could launch some unexpected fireworks, so this would be a work-around:

```
Dim index As Integer = cbBox.SelectedIndex
RemoveHandler cbBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cbBox_SelectedIndexChanged
dictStrings.Add("new key", "new value")
cbBox.DataSource = New BindingSource(dictStrings.Keys, Nothing)
cbBox.SelectedIndex = index
AddHandler cbBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cbBox_SelectedIndexChanged
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried cbBox.DataSource.refresh ?

Comment: I get this: Public member 'Refresh' on type 'BindingSource' not found

Comment: There is no such method.

Answer (score -1):

```
ComboBox1.Update()
```

Should fix the issue.

EDIT : `cbBox.Update()`